# QT4 : How to run multiple shell commands with QProcess?

Tags: qt, shell, ssh, qprocess

I'm just starting to play around with QT and want to create a simple GUI for some shell scripts I use.

I'd like to do two simple actions :

1. connect to a server with SSH
2. run a command once connected to the server (a mysqldump for ex.)

So far I manage to do the SSH connexion like this :

```
QStringList args_ssh;
args_ssh << ui->lineEdit_sshUser->text() + "@" + ui->lineEdit_sshHost->text();
commandProcess.start("ssh", args_ssh);
```

That works fine, it prompts for the password and connects. But how can I execute further commands from there ? I tried to start a second commandProcess just under, but that doesn't seem to be the way.

Answer (score 1):

QProcess is derived from QIODevice which means you can [read from/write to](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qprocess.html#communicating-via-channels) it like a file. After the process is started, send your followup commands via standard QIODevice calls.

Comment: not sure how to add a followup command . for example first command cd than /dir